# Aggregation relationship in Java

Tags: java

The following is a Java code demonstrating the use of 'Aggregation' or has -a relationship in Java.

```
class Address{
    private String addressLine;
    public String getAddressLine(){
        return addressLine;
    }
    public void setAddressLine(String address){
        addressLine=address;
    }
}
class Customer{
    private int customerId;
    private Address address;
    private static int counter = 1000;
    public Customer{
        customerId=++counter;
    }
    public int getCustomerId(){
        return customerId;
    }
    public void set Address(Address address){
        this.address=address;
    }
    public Address getAddress(){
        return address;
    }
}
class Retail{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Address add=new Address();
        add.setAddressLine("Washington Street");
        Customer custObj = new Customer();
        custObj.setAddress(add);
        Address temp = custObj.getAddress();
        System.out.println("Address");
        System.out.println(temp.getAdressLine());
    }
}
```

Unable to understand certain parts of the code here. Kindly explain the program execution.
Also, why do we have to store the value of get address in temp to print it? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: For 1) Can you elaborate on which parts you do not understand? For 2) Did you try `System.out.println(custObj.getAddress().getAdressLine());`?

Comment: What parts don't you understand? There are almost always other ways to do it (whatever "it" is).

Comment: In this case, it's stored in temp so you don't need to call the getAddress() function twice, which in certain cases can be costly.

Comment: In Customer class, we are declaring "private Address address;" What happens one this gets executed? Is it a instance variable address of class Address?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be test program to either learn how to set and get the aggregation properties.

In the actual scenario,

```
Address add=new Address();
add.setAddressLine("Washington Street");
Customer custObj = new Customer();
custObj.setAddress(add); 
saveCustomer(custObj);
```

This part will be in first class and

```
Customer custObj = getCustomer();
Address temp = custObj.getAddress();
System.out.println("Address");
```

will be in other file.

1st part you might be saving it to some database or in cache etc. While in 2nd part you might want to fetch the same from db/cache.